# Mapkit - Swift4 - How to disable Auto zooming

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, zooming

Apologies for the absurdely junior question but for some reason I can't grasp how to stop this from happening.

When I run the app, and I pinch to zoom into the map (or out, or navigate away from my position) the app will always pull me back to a set height and to my location. I'd like to not have this happen and just have the experience of zooming to whatever level and moving around without being interrupted.

Any ideas?

Here's the code snip from my VC:

```
let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 2000
func centerMapOnLocation(location: CLLocation) {
let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location.coordinate, regionRadius, regionRadius)

    mapView.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: true)
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations[0]

    let center = location.coordinate
    let span = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)
    let region  = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: span)

    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true

}
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Call `requestLocation` instead of `startUpdatingLocation` on your location manager if you just want to set the map's region to the user's location once instead of constantly updating it.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you v much. From how you explain it, that's what I'm looking to achieve. However when I do the replacement you suggested the app suddenly starts having a SIGABRT error when launching (Note, building works ok without throwing any error).  I'm not sure why - as I haven't change any of the attributes it seems to dislike at the start of the debug error (compass, scale). I suspected it was my connections. But I don't see any problematic connections on my VCs. The debug console error is here:
 [link (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VnzwhO8yV5Y2MKZ581wznLtISMZmHN_z24iJUFidAZI/edit)

Comment: Thank @dan, not me. He posted the comment. I simply made an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Location Manager delegate methods can be called very frequently and at any time. So you need to stop updating locations.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()
    manager.delegate = nil

    let location = locations[0]
    ...
}
```